# How do I programmatically cycle a router?

Tags: cycle, router

I have the need to be able to cycle my linksys router via a program, the reason I want to do this is complex, so let's just assume there is no better option.

Is there anyway to do this?  I think there is because when I install a firmware update to the router via the admin console, it cycles the router.

Answer (score 5):

If you can find the function to do that on the router's web interface, you can achieve the same via a suitable HTTP request.  Also, you can often telnet to the router and reboot it through its command-line interface.  Programmatically you can achieve the same, by using a tool like [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the local web interface of the router you might be able to access the "reset" function of the router. You can try to call this via a http request, e.g. via wget. But this depends very much on the router. Some routers also support SNMP or a telnet interface.

Another possibility is to plug the router into an ethernet-connected power strip which can be remotely controlled. These power strips usually have a simple http server build in, so you can individually switch on and off the devices that are connected.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Linksys WRT54G, I highly recommend DD-WRT. It's an open source firmware replacement, and it has this feature built in for timed restarts. A programmatic restart with an HTTP request should be quite easy as well, as the restart function is available through the admin GUI.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/danielrussellLA/restart-linksys-EA2700-router you can try using a nightwatch bot similar to this one to programatically restart your router through its browser ui. This works well if your router does not have a command line interface that you can access (through telnet, ssh etc). It's pretty hacky, but it gets the job done.